# Inplace filter and collect to List

Tags: java, spring

Required a snippet demonstrating how filtering and collecting can be done inplace on a list?

For example, I have:

```
filteredProducts = Products.stream().filter(product -> {
  // filtering on some parameters
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I wanted to do something inplace filtering in the Products collection itself.

Something like (illegal):

```
Products.stream().filter(product -> {
  // filtering on some parameters
}).collect(
  // collect to same list(collection)
);
```

Do someone knows any legal way for doing inplace filtering on a collection? That will be helpful! Thanks a lot!

PS: I already am using removeIf method, if that you were going to suggest!

Comment: Are you saying that method [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) is not sufficient?

Comment: Considering some performance aspects removeIf might be inefficient ( Runtime POV ).

Answer (score 2):

`Stream`s cannot not modify the underlying list in-place. If you need to modify the collection itself, either use the `removeIf` method like you already mentioned, or use an iterator:

```
Iterator<Product> iterator = products.iterator()
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Product next = iterator.next()
  if (/* filter using next value */) iterator.remove()
}
```